# How do I recode several columns by name in R in a "tidyverse" way?

Tags: r

I have several columns in a data frame that I'm trying to recode and would like to do it in a way that's more elegant than I'm currently doing.

Here's my data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("Joe","Bob","Sue","Tim", "Steve"), 
                 X1=c("Always", "Sometimes", "Often", "Never", NA), 
                 X2=c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"),
                 X3=c("Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Never", "Always", "Always"))
```

```
name    X1          X2    X3
Joe     Always      Yes   Sometimes
Bob     Sometimes   No    Sometimes
Sue     Often       No    Never
Tim     Never       Yes   Always
Steve   NA          Yes   Always
```

My current method of recoding is quite inelegant:

```
for(i in c(2, 4)){
  df[,paste(colnames(df), '_recode', sep="")[i]] = ifelse(df[,i] == 'Always', 1, 
                                                                                  ifelse(df[,i] == 'Often', 2,
                                                                                         ifelse(df[,i] == 'Sometimes', 3,
                                                                                                ifelse(df[,i] == 'Never', 4,
                                                                                                       NA))))
}
```

I'd like to be able to reference the columns by name instead of by index so that the code is more stable. I'd also like to do this in tidyverse if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across`.  Loop over the columns 2 and 4 in `across`, use a named vector or a key/value vector to match and replace the values in the column and rename the column with suffix "recode" in `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
      mutate(across(c(2, 4),  ~ setNames(1:4, c("Always", "Often", 
         "Sometimes", "Never"))[.], .names = "{.col}_recode"))
```

-output

```
df1
#   name        X1  X2        X3 X1_recode X3_recode
#1   Joe    Always Yes Sometimes         1         3
#2   Bob Sometimes  No Sometimes         3         3
#3   Sue     Often  No     Never         2         4
#4   Tim     Never Yes    Always         4         1
#5 Steve      <NA> Yes    Always        NA         1
```

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. One question: You're still referring to the columns by their indices, correct? (In c(2, 4).) Is there any way to do it using the column names and not indices? Thanks! Also, what is the [.] for? Thanks!

Comment: @Mark You can either use indices or names, `c(X1, X3)` instead of `c(2, 4)`.  The `.` is the column value from the anonymous function `~` similar to function(x)

Comment: @Mark I added some info.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fct_recode` from package `forcats` a member of `tidyverse` family:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(X1 = factor(X1),
         X3 = factor(X3),
         X1 = fct_recode(X1, "1" = "Always", "2" = "Often" , "3" =  "Sometimes", 
                         "4" = "Never"),
         X3 = fct_recode(X3, "1" = "Always", "3" =  "Sometimes", 
                         "4" = "Never"))

   name   X1  X2 X3
1   Joe    1 Yes  3
2   Bob    3  No  3
3   Sue    2  No  4
4   Tim    4 Yes  1
5 Steve <NA> Yes  1
```